# Mysql database data format in .net

Tags: mysql, asp.net, date

Hi I will use mysql db in my project. The database using with php now. I will use with asp.net. Tables have data column and date like this : 1289053800.

How can I convert this value to .net datetime.

Regards

Comment: what is the data type for date column?

Comment: How do you interpret the shown datetime. Is it in `'%m%d%y%h%i%s'` format or something else?

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAnsari int(15)

Comment: @Ravinder I have no Idea, I need like this dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm

Comment: Why are you using `int` for storing `date`, use `datetime` format.

Comment: and use `select DATE_FORMAT(date_column,'%d.%m.%Y %H.%i')
from your_table` to fetch date in dd.mm.yyyy hh.mm format

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAnsari select DATE_FORMAT(date_column,'%d.%m.%Y %H.%i') from your_table returned null.

Comment: put your date column name instead of `date_column` and your table name instead of `your_table`

Comment: yes I did, select DATE_FORMAT(tarih,'%d/%m/%Y'),macID from  cblcomtrsql.maclar returned null

Comment: r u sure that the table contains some records???
Check this [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5098d/12) i have created sample table and query for the same

Comment: yes sure : 1289059200
1289140200
1289145600
1289151000
1290879000
1290873600

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50951/discussion-between-abdulrahman-ansari-and-onder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your date time values are stored in `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` format.

You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME` on them to convert to regular `datetime` type.

```
select
    date_cloumn -- that has 1289053800 kind of values
  , from_unixtime( date_cloumn ) as dt_f_ut
  , date_format( from_unixtime( date_cloumn ), '%d.%m.%Y %h.%i' ) as dt_f_ut_12hr
  , date_format( from_unixtime( date_cloumn ), '%d.%m.%Y %H.%i' ) as dt_f_ut_24hr
from table_name
;
```

Using `.Net`, you may need no changes but just read:

- a `DateTime` on `dt_f_ut` or
- a `String` on `dt_f_ut_12hr` or
- a `String` on `dt_f_ut_24hr` or
  into desired variables.

**Demo** @ [***MySQL 5.5.32 Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/168be/1)

**Refer to**:

- [*FROM_UNIXTIME()*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

  - Format UNIX timestamp as a date
- [*UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

  - Return a UNIX timestamp